# Unit test setup never invoked

Tags: linq, unit-testing, moq, verify

I'm trying to write a unit test to test a method which basically takes in some data groups it and then runs a method. For some reason my setup is never invoked. I've debugged and I've checked the types passed in and out and the data and it is exactly the same after the grouping. Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

This is in my test:

```
MyArray[] grouped = myArray
                    .SelectMany(x => x.AccountValues)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
                    .Select(g2 => 
                        new AccountValue { 
                                Amount = g2.Sum(x => x.Amount), 
                                TimeStamp = g2.Key })
                    .ToArray();

helper
   .Setup(s => s.Compute(grouped, grouped.Count())
   .Returns(someValue);

var result = _engine.Get(accountNumbers, startDate, endDate, code);

helper.Verify(v => v.Compute(grouped, grouped.Count()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

The actual method which i'm testing is as follows:

```
public decimal? Get(long[] accountNumbers, 
                          DateTime startDate, 
                          DateTime endDate, 
                          long code)
{
        var accountNumbersInt = Array.ConvertAll(accountNumbers, i => (int)i);

        var myArray = TransactionManager
                             .Get(accountNumbersInt, startDate, endDate, code);

        var accountValues = GroupData(myArray);
        var result= Helper.Compute(accountValues, accountValues.Count());
        return result;
}

internal myArray[] GroupData(Account[] myArray)
{
    var grouped = myArray
                       .SelectMany(x => x.AccountValues)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
                       .Select(g2 => 
                          new AccountValue { 
                                   Amount = g2.Sum(x => x.Amount), 
                                   TimeStamp = g2.Key })
                       .ToArray();
    return grouped;
}
```

EDIT: helper is set as follows in the test setup

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _engine = new CalcEngine();
    helper = new Mock<IHelper>();
    _engine.Helper = helper.Object;
}
```

Comment: What is helper? Usually that would be run when executing your actual test, it shouldn't change when you first step over that particular line when debugging.

Comment: how did you mock the helper? this is important information, because we cant see if you are actually calling the helper, or the helper mock - maybe this is the mistake

Comment: @Stephan - edited the post with the helper code

Comment: have you tried verifying this: `helper.Verify(v => v.Compute(It.IsAny<MyArray[]>(), It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Exactly(1));` -> if this verifies, then you know the mock is called, but the parameters are asserted wrong, if not then the mock is never called

Comment: Yup, that works, but the parameters are setup correctly as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

This part here, doesn't invoke your method:

```
helper
   .Setup(s => s.Compute(grouped, grouped.Count())
   .Returns(someValue);
```

The way your test is written, I presume that you're testing your `_engine.Get()` method.
The idea is that you would create a mock, pass it to the method you're testing (different ways to do that) call the method you're testing and then observe what else was called as a result (side effects).

I see that in your `Get()` method you're doing the following:

```
var result= Helper.Compute(accountValues, accountValues.Count());
```

Presuming `Helper` is the same that you're trying to verify you need to pass it from your unit test, so something like:

```
helper
   .Setup(s => s.Compute(grouped, grouped.Count())
   .Returns(someValue);

_engine.Helper = helper.Object;

// your verifications here ...
```

Comment: helper is set up like that, which is why it's so bizarre

Comment: @newbie_86 the way I see it, you need to mock your `TransactioManager` and set it up to return the array that you've created in your unit test. Currently the Verify would fall, because you're not calling the method with the same object (the same result set)